# Retry mechanism in PromiseKit 6 by making extra call in recover

Tags: swift, promisekit

I would like to know if the below scenario can be achieved using PromiseKit 6. If so, please suggest the best way to do this.

```
firstly {
    makeAPICall()
}.recover { error in
    // if error != session expired throw error
    renewTokens().done { foo in
       makeAPICall() // Make the same API call again
    }
}.done { foo in
    //…
}.catch { error in
    //…
}
```

Comment: What is `firstly`? Is it needed for the question, or can it be replaced by `makeAPICall()`? Also, should we assume that `makeAPICall` returns a `Promise`? Or at least a `Thenable`?

Comment: `firstly` is optional and just for readability. And yes, `makeAPICall()` returns a Promise.